# Dynamically setting colortable to volume

Tags: xtk

The following snippet doesn't seem to do anything after the volume was rendered.

`volume.colortable.file = file;
volume.modified();
r.render();`

Also, placing `volume.colortable.file = file;` after `r.add(volume)` causes a "y is undefined" error.

The latest xtk_edge.js was used.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. The color table need to be attached during parsing to properly configure the texture of the volume/labelmap. There is also no easy way around that in my eyes.

Comment: Okay. The renderer could be reused if there is a renderer.remove(volume).